# Run a small scale DDoS attack against a Raspberry Pi Server

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, ddos

For a networking class, I want to do a presentation and project on DDoS attacks. I have been researching them for a while and am interested in conducting a small scale attack against a victim server with no security (I'll most likely set this up using nginx or apache) running on a Raspberry Pi. I want to run a demo of this happening in class - first with no security, and then a few other times - each time adding another layer of security.

Does anyone have an idea how much traffic I would need in order to take this down? Also what would be the best way to generate this traffic? I'm not sure if this part is even possible as I don't have access to a lot of computers...I do have a mac pro with 24GB of ram so I have been considering running several virtual boxes with that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is likely off-topic for StackOverflow, but I'd recommend researching `LOIC` (low orbit ion cannon, commonly used for DOSing).

Comment: It may be, but I thought it was worth a try! Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working locally using nginx on the Pi and LOIC.

Comment: Cool, I love LOIC used in academic settings.